# Run time error 1004 for pivot table creation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table from a .csv file. But I am having a run time error 1004: Reference is not valid over at the ActiveWorkbook portion of the code.

Any suggestions for this?

My code is as follows

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Sheets.Add
ws.Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ws.Name & "R1C1:R101643C21", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10

End Sub
```

I did a Sheets.Add to add in new worksheet. I used a ws.Name as the name can be any name. Just an addition question, is it possible to change R1C1:R101643C21 to a varying range as the data may not be that big or small?

Comment: 1) `ws` is empty before `ws.Select`.

2) yes, you can use a dynamic range. you can use another variable to store the range

Comment: @sam092 hi, I left out the Set ws = ActiveSheet in the code posted earlier on. I have it in my macro but it still show the error

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a dynamic range.  You may be getting an error if you try to create additional tables with the same name and destination?

Comment: @DavidZemens what do you mean by create additional tables? U mean in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the `!` in SourceData. The missing `!` is causing the invalid reference

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        ws.Name & "!R1C1:R11C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10

End Sub
```

For dynamic range, see this

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B10")

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        rng, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10

End Sub
```

Just a reminder, you are only creating a empty pivot table in this way

Comment: hey thanks! Its a great help to identify the !. Also thanks for the additional codes.